# Can't get drop event working with HTML5 Drag and drop API

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I've been trying to get the drop event since hours. All others events works fine. dragover ok. dragenter ok. etc But not the drop event.

Here's the JS code :

```
function onDragStart(event)
{
    console.log("dragStart");
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "data");
}

function onDrop(event)
{
    console.log('onDrop');
}
document.querySelector('span[draggable="true"]').addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart, false);
document.querySelector('#cell_1').addEventListener('drop', onDrop, false);
```

The HTML is something like :

```
<div id="cell_1" class="cell"><span draggable="true">1</span></div>
```

With grid css layout.

Answer (score 1):

I've embedded the events inside the tags but you can still use `querySelectors` #LazyCoding

Here's what I got with the help of [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

I'm pretty sure you need to use `dragOver` too, to allow for dropping but I'm not 100% certain.

---

```js
function onDragStart(event) {
  console.log("dragStart");
  
  // Add the target element's id to the data transfer object
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.id);
  event.dropEffect = "move";
}

function onDragOver(event) {
  console.log("dragOver");
  
  event.preventDefault();
  // Set the dropEffect to move
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"
}

function onDrop(event) {
  console.log("drop");
  
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get the id of the target and add the moved element to the target's DOM
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}

span {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<span id="myCustomId" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
Drag Me
</span>

<div id="cell_1" class="cell" ondrop="onDrop(event);" ondragover="onDragOver(event);">
  Drop Zone
</div>
```

Comment: You're right Alex, thank you. I don't know why but it needs preventDefault() on the dragover event ! :)

Comment: `preventDefault` I understand why but still confused about `dragOver` though :) No problem. Enjoy!